# angular nvd3 display issue in ios device that is not showing up on ios emulator

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, nvd3.js, angularjs-nvd3-directives, angular-nvd3

In the ios emulator for ionic I can see the various stackedAreaCharts using angular-nvd3 directives I am drawing. I get the following error only in the emulator, but not when I run the app using ionic serve on localhost.

Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'options.chart.type')
updateWithOptions@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-nvd3/1.0.5/angular-nvd3.min.js:1:3415
refresh@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-nvd3/1.0.5/angular-nvd3.min.js:1:2966
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-nvd3/1.0.5/angular-nvd3.min.js:1:6809
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-nvd3/1.0.5/angular-nvd3.min.js:1:7896
$digest@file:///Users/griffinadams/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/04E08EF7-3015-4006-BF43-3CB80F01650D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/99911A93-AADE-4A8F-A27E-6FF48A023009/DigitalAgent-Sidemenu.app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24515:31
$apply@file:///Users/griffinadams/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/04E08EF7-3015-4006-BF43-3CB80F01650D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/99911A93-AADE-4A8F-A27E-6FF48A023009/DigitalAgent-Sidemenu.app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24783:31
done@file:///Users/griffinadams/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/04E08EF7-3015-4006-BF43-3CB80F01650D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/99911A93-AADE-4A8F-A27E-6FF48A023009/DigitalAgent-Sidemenu.app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:19196:53
completeRequest@file:///Users/griffinadams/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/04E08EF7-3015-4006-BF43-3CB80F01650D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/99911A93-AADE-4A8F-A27E-6FF48A023009/DigitalAgent-Sidemenu.app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:19368:15
requestLoaded@file:///Users/griffinadams/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/04E08EF7-3015-4006-BF43-3CB80F01650D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/99911A93-AADE-4A8F-A27E-6FF48A023009/DigitalAgent-Sidemenu.app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:19309:24

Once again, the graphs draw fine in the emulator and localhost, but do not display and I am pretty sure are causing the code to stop running in the iPad or any other ios device.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it on an ios device instead of relying on an emulator.  I have had very bad luck with the emulator.